# Integrating code between versioned and non versioned projects

Tags: git, integration

We outsourced a part of our project to another company and we are also developing it in-house. We are using GIT in-house, but the other company is not. Since we are near our deadlines, we dont have time to train up those people on GIT.

Manual integration of files would be hectic and I am in need of some way to integrate with their non-versioned code.

Here is a few tricks I tried, but didnt work out:
I created a new branch 'test' from my main branch 'main', replaced ALL the files from them in that branch. So, now my main branch 'main' contains our work and 'test' branch contains other's work.

I had files m1, m2, m3 in my branch 'main', and they got deleted while I replaced ALL files and folders. I thought merging 'test' and 'main' would be suffice and bring back the deleted files, but it is not. I think its because 'test' is derived from 'main'.

I am a GIT beginner and dont know the concepts of cherry-picking / rebase. But if those would help, I am very much willing to learn those.

Could someone advice me on the right way to integrate the project?

Edit: what Tomas Markauskas told seems to be a perfect solution for me. But unfortunately, we already got a release from the other company and what I am doing right now is

- created a new branch 'out'
- pasted their code in it
- listed the diff using `git diff out --stat`
- keeping the list as a checklist manually checking out, skipping individual files (where only one of made some changes)

but for files where we both did some changes, I suppose I need to merge them individually and do a manual resolve, reading through all the lines of code in those lines..

Is there any better way than this?

Comment: Ohh, hope the guys who organized the outsourcing learned something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a branch for the other company. Every time they update the code you could just replace the old files with the new ones and commit it. Every commit would represent a release. You could then easily merge it into your working branch.

To avoid deleting of files that were deleted in the other branch you could merge the branches without committing the merge (`--no-commit`). Then just revert the changes you don't want to apply and commit.